# Sometimes I can edit and continue, sometimes I can't in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I debug a unit test from the Test Explorer, I am unable to make edits to the code once a breakpoint is hit.

I have Edit and Continue enabled.

I get the following error when I change a line of code, even though there are no compile errors:

[image]

I am just changing an integer assignment:

> testJob.NumberOfDesigns = 2;

to

> testJob.NumberOfDesigns = 4;

Is there a way to get this working again?

Comment: Not all changes can be continued, per example you can't change the code of a lambda expression, or you can't change the code of the executing line, you must be trying to change something that prevents edit and continue.

Comment: @Gusman See edits

Comment: Edit and Continue can only work under a very limited set of code changes, which Microsoft documents in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Continue supports most changes you might want to make during a debugging session, but there are some exceptions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx

Edit and Continue is supported for 64-bit projects that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1. Use Any CPu